# Mongo custom repository naming problems

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

I have definitions:

```
public interface  FruitsRepository extends MongoRepository<Fruits, String>,  FruitsRepositoryCustom {
...
}

public interface  FruitsRepositoryCustom {
...
}

public class FruitsRepositoryImpl implements  FruitsRepositoryCustom {
...
}
```

When I try to change the name of  `FruitsRepositoryImpl` to  `FruitsRepositoryXImpl` it is no recognized by spring and I am getting exception. What is the cause of this and how can I change the name of class that implements by custom interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom repository implementation name postfix is `Impl` by default.

In order to change it to `XImpl` you should change the `repository-impl-postfix` attribute of the `repositories` element. Something such as:

`<repositories repository-impl-postfix="XImpl" base-package=...>`

Or by using Java:

`@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryImplementationPostfix="Ximpl" basePackages=...)`

However, note that changing the postfix name applies to all custom repositories.

See more at [the reference documentation, namespace reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.namespace-reference)